# How to call external commands in Scheme?

Tags: scripting, scheme, lisp

Is it possible to call external commands in Scheme on a Unix system? What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: See [Execute command line from Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33210533/4739247).

Comment: @assefamaru Not the same question as it asks especially after `guile`, while this question doesn't.

Comment: What did you try already? Have you tried to read a manual - sounds old fashioned - but Scheme systems usual have some documentation. I would expect that most Scheme implementations on Unix can call external programs.

Comment: I looked everywhere including this site, but I didn't find anything for scheme specifically.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such features and FFI (Foreign function interface) is not part of the Scheme standard.

There are implementations that extend Scheme with other features and Racket is one of them.

Chicken Scheme has an [extension to call a command](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/shell) and several FFIs, including [Lazy FFI](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/lazy-ffi).

Racket has the possibility to execute commands though [Processes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html) and it also has [FFI](https://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/) making it possible to interface with anything on your machine.

There is a [related question specific to Guile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210533/execute-command-line-from-scheme-guile) version of Scheme.

Since you have tagged Lisp, there is a [related question specific to Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065446/executing-a-shell-command-from-common-lisp).

Comment: Hmm...given there isn't a way to call external binaries in scheme generally, do you know any scheme-derived language that allows for this and is good for unix scripting? (I rather wouldn't use racket because it's a bit bloated and simplicity and 'niceness' are the reason I'm trying to move away from bash.

Comment: @user279540 I've added Chicken, but I do not use it much. You probably could look the [different implementations](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards#implementations) and fin the best one for you.

Comment: @user279540  There's scsh but is seems a while since anyone updated it.

Comment: The minimal racket distribution on MacOS is an 8.6MB DMG file, it's not that huge.

Comment: I have heard of scsh, but was reluctant to use it for that very reason.